# maven could not resolve dependencies for jmonkeyengine

Tags: java, maven, jmonkeyengine

I am trying learn the jmonkey engine and want to set up a maven project. I copied the maven setup from the jmonkey website in to my pom and still get a error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project jmonkey.test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:jmonkey.test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-core:jar:3.2.0-stable: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-core:jar:3.2.0-stable: Could not transfer artifact org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-core:pom:3.2.0-stable from/to jcenter (http://jcenter.bintray.com): Access denied to http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jmonkeyengine/jme3-core/3.2.0-stable/jme3-core-3.2.0-stable.pom. Error code 403, Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

I don't now what to do to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are somehow trying to fetch the dependency from jcenter over http. You should try fetching it over **https**. That is why you get a 403 status code from jcenter.